# What algorithm can I use for encryption in Java?

Tags: java, encryption

What algorithm can I use for creating an encryption program in Java? What if I want to use the same key for encrypting and decrypting?

Example: I type `Hello world` and use the key `guy`, so the words change into `xgdsts@dtoll`. If I want to decrypt it, I have to use the same key(`guy`) so it'll become `hello world` again

Comment: Just to aid you when googling, what you describe is typically called "symmetric-key encryption".

Comment: I think it's funny that the question puts a TM on Java, but does not capitalize the name as would be required for the trademark to actually apply.

Comment: sorry oneal, i'm not aware of that :D

Answer (score 3):

You could use [AES](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html).

Comment: @WenZ, try the link I have posted. It contains a sample.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use any algorithm you want, if you're willing to implement it. If you're asking what algorithms Java provides, the [cryptography extension](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) offers (from [this list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher)):

- AES
- Blowfish
- DES
- DESede
- RC2, RC4, RC5
- RSA

I believe all those are **symmetric** (the encryption and decryption key is the same) except for RSA

Comment: That link is to the Java 1.4 documentation. I haven't looked around, but you might want to either annotate that or link to a more recent version of that documentation.

Comment: @Thomas I'm having trouble finding the newer documentation, but I added a note in the answer

Comment: You might want to check it out to verify, but http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html appears to be the Java 6 version of what you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Java Cryptography Extension](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html).  Here's a [simple example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/Basicsymmetricencryptionexample.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to the industry standards - Triple-DES (3DES) or AES, whereby 3DES is slowly being replaced by AES. Libraries and source code for various languages are available, tested and validated.

I would use random generated keys for data encryption, and distribute these keys using asymetric methods (RSA) based on public/private key pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any [symmetric key algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm)